# How to return from Dispatch.Invoke after given timespan

Tags: wpf, invoke, dispatcher, timespan

I am trying to use below Dispatcher Invoke API (.Net 4.6) as I want to return back if my delegate is taking time. Problem is that Dispatcher.Invoke doesn't return until delegate is done

Sample code:

```
    public void PopulateList()
    {
        List<string> tempList = null;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new TimeSpan(0,0,10), (Action)delegate ()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);//Sleep for 20 secs
            tempList = new List<string>();
        });

        if (tempList == null)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

TimeSpan is set to 10 sec, hence I believe Dispatcher should come out after 10 secs with tempList still null. But Thread sleeps well for 20 sec and tempList is not null.

I understand that Invoke is a synchronous operation and wont return until job is done - that is why i added TimeSpan to return after a while even if job is not finished.

What is incorrect here?

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code for that [method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,1211) in the `Dispatcher` class, and the documentation (.NET 4.7.2) for the `timeout` parameter says:

```
/// <param name="timeout">
///     The minimum amount of time to wait for the operation to start.
///     Once the operation has started, it will complete before this method
///     returns.
/// </param>
```

However, in my documentation (.NET 4.5) for the `timeout` parameter says:

```
//   timeout:
//     The maximum time to wait for the operation to finish.
```

So in .NET 4.5 (and I'm guessing .NET 4.6) it does make you think that the method should stop if it's been running for longer than `timeout`, but that's different from the .NET 4.7.2 description. Now, either the functionality has changed (I doubt it), or they cleared up the meaning of `timeout`.

Comment: Yes, this is very confusing, couldn't find documentation for .Net 4.6 version

Answer (score 0):

Just found that `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` works if given for a timeout value

```
public void PopulateList()
    {
        List<string> tempList = null;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), (Action)delegate ()
        {
            //any heavy processing work here will be done, 
            //just dont know when timeout is reached and dispatcher 
            //comes out of this delegate
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);//Sleep for 20 milli secs
            tempList = new List<string>();
        });

        if (tempList == null)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

tempList remains null in this case. I also tried setting sleep after setting tempList, but it still remains null. I am using .NET 4.6.2 hence I believe TimeSpan is timeout value for dispatcher. No exceptions thrown.

Thanks,

RDV